# Why is this defined even when divided by zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

so I've got $$\dfrac{x^3-4x^2+3x}{x^2-1}$$ and want to calculate the asymptotes. There's one a $x=-1$ since the function is not defined there. But the function seems to be defined for $x=1$. How come? 
It should be undefined at $x=1$ since $f(1)=1^2-1 = 0$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Asymptotes_for_rational_functions :  "The vertical asymptotes occur only when the denominator is zero (If both the numerator and denominator are zero, the multiplicities of the zero are compared)"

Comment: It is a commonplace mistake to think that there is an asymptote wherever the denominator is $0$.  When you divide one continuous function by another, there is a vertical asymptote wherever the denominator is $0$ AND the numerator is NOT $0$.

Comment: It's not defined there, but it can be made continuous there...

Comment: The function isn't defined there, but as the denominator gets closer and closer to $0$, the numerator also gets closer and closer to $0$, so the function value doesn't blow up like with an asymptote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Factor the numerator: $x^3 - 4x^2 + 3x = x(x-1)(x-3)$. Cancel the common factor in the numerator and denominator: $$\dfrac{x(x-1)(x - 3)}{(x - 1)(x + 1)} = \dfrac{x(x-3)}{x+1}$$

However, please note that the original function is NOT defined at $x = 1$. But no asymptote exists there because it is a [removable discontinuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_discontinuity).

Vertical asymptotes occur only when the denominator is zero, but they *don't necessarily* occur when the denominator is zero.

In the case $x = -1$, the denominator is zero, so we have a *potential* asymptote at $x = -1$. Indeed, the numerator of the given function is *not* zero at $x = -1$, and hence an asymptote *does in fact* exist, and is given by the vertical line $x = -1$.

On the other hand, in the case $x = 1$, while the denominator is zero (and hence we need to determine whether or not an asymptote exists there), we see that the numerator also evaluates to $0$ at $x = 1$. Indeed, we see that, both numerator and denominator share a common factor $x - 1$, which can be canceled, and hence the discontinuity at $x = 1$ can be *removed.* So, in fact, **no** asymptote exists at $x = 1$.

Suggestion: graph the original function to get an visual idea of what's happening with the given function.

Answer (score 6):

The function, as presented, *is* undefined when $x=1$. However, the discontinuity is [removable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_discontinuity) since the numerator has a factor of $x-1$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not defined at $x = 1$; at that point it has a "removable singualarity;" you would show this on a graph by putting a white (hollow) dot at that point.  At a removable singularity, you can redefine the function to make it continuous.  But that changes the function. Conclusion:  Removable singularities are not in the domain of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a factor $(x-1)$ in the numerator.
$$x^3-4x^2+3x=x(x-3)(x-1).$$ So the $(x-1)$ factor in the denominators cancels off.